# C# Code loops unwantedly, winform, dataset, sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, loops, listbox

I have a winform with listboxes that are filled thourgh listbox.DataSource on the event of another listbox_SelectedIndexChanged. This should create a cascade through the listboxes; if listbox1(lbCat) changes, then the query for listbox2(lbFam) changes hence its datasource changes, and so for listbox3(lbProd).

However, the output window shows that upon starting the winform, this cascading happens 3 times instead of 1... And I can't figure out why!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;

namespace LookApp2016
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
```

just setting up some string to use later on, skip this part if you will

```
        // De naam van de tabel waaruit de productcodes worden gelezen
        string sDBproducts = "productinfo_2016";
        string sDBFamily = "familyinfo_2016";
    //kolomnamen van productinfo (zodat bij aanpassing in database alle sql queries direct veranderen)
    string sColumnNameProductcode = "productcode";
    string sColumnnameCatalogus = "catalogue";
    string sColumnNameFamily = "productfamily";

    string sColumnNameProductDescription;
    string sColumnNameSizeCM;
    string sColumnNameSizeInch;

    //kolomnamen van familyinfo (zodat bij aanpassing in database alle sql queries direct veranderen)
    string sColumnNameRenDContact = "rend_contact";
    string sColumnNameSpecsGeneral = "specs"; //wel nog taal toevoegen aan deze string!!

    // Strings aanmaken voor de mogelijke keuzes in de listboxes zodat deze(vooraf aan user input) toegevoegd kunnen worden aan de queries waarmee de datasets gemaakt worden.
    string queryCategorie = "'A'";
    string queryValuta = "EUR";
    string queryTaal = "nl";
    string sSelectedFamily = "R&R Curve";
    string productcode = "R&R-C-200-60";
    string sFamilie = null;


    //strings aanmaken voor invoegen in excel, start met NL
    string sStuk = "stuk";
    string sStuk_multi = "stuks";
    string sMeter = "meter";
    string sMeter_multi = "meter";
    string sM2 = "m2";
    string sM2_multi = "m2";
    string sSet = "set";
    string sSet_multi = "sets";
    string s0 = "n.v.t.";
    string sEenheid = "eenheid";
    string sAantal = "Aantal";
    string sTotaal = "Totaal";
    string sSpecificaties = "Algemene informatie:";
    string sPrijs = "Prijs";

    string sEenheidBijProductcode = "stuk"; // gelezen uit productinfo, niet familyinfo

    SizeF sAIsize;
    float cellHeight;

    // Een decimal aanmaken zodat de prijs in de juiste valuta weergegeven kan worden.
    double valutaConverter;

    string A = "A__Straatmeubilair";
    string B = "B__Boomproducten";
    string C = "C__Bruggen";

    string NL = "NL";
    string EN = "GB";
    string ENI = "ENint";
    string DE = "DE";
    string FR = "FR";
    string SP = "SP";
```

so this is where I set my SqlConnection

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source =MILKYWAY; Initial Catalog = 'SPD'; User Id=*******; Password = *******;");


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine(" Opstart tijd" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
        conn.Open();
        // De categorieën aan de lbCategorie toevoegen en A selecteren
        lbCat.Items.Add(A);
        lbCat.Items.Add(B);
        lbCat.Items.Add(C);
        lbCat.SetSelected(0, true);

        // De valuta-opties aan de lbValuta toevoegen en EUR selecteren
        lbValuta.Items.Add("EUR      (x1)");
        lbValuta.Items.Add("GBP   (x0.65)");
        lbValuta.Items.Add("USD    (x1.4)");
        lbValuta.Items.Add("CAD    (x1.5)");
        lbValuta.Items.Add("OIL   (x1.05)");
        lbValuta.SetSelected(0, true);   // EUR is pre-selected

        // De taal-opties aan de lbTaal toevoegen en NL selecteren
        lbTaal.Items.Add(NL);
        lbTaal.Items.Add(EN);
        lbTaal.Items.Add(ENI);
        lbTaal.Items.Add(DE);
        lbTaal.Items.Add(FR);
        lbTaal.Items.Add(SP);
        lbTaal.SetSelected(0, true);   // NL is pre-selected

    }


    private void lbCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //FAMILIE LISTBOX VULLEN ADHV GEKOZEN CATEGORIE
        queryCategorie = lbCat.Text.Remove(1);
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~GEKOZEN CATEGORIE: " + queryCategorie + ". Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Remove(0, 14));
        lbFamVullen();
    }

    private void lbFamVullen()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT " + sColumnNameFamily + " FROM " + sDBproducts + " WHERE " + sColumnnameCatalogus + " LIKE '" + queryCategorie + "'";
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~DE lbFAM wordt gevuld met de query: " + sql + ". Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Remove(0, 14));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        lbFam.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        lbFam.DisplayMember = sColumnNameFamily;
        lbFam.ValueMember = sColumnNameFamily;

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

    private void lbFam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sSelectedFamily = lbFam.Text;
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~De lbFam index changed. De geselcteerde familie = " + sSelectedFamily + ". Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Remove(0,14));
        lbProdVullen();
    }

    private void lbProdVullen()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT " + sColumnNameProductcode + " FROM " + sDBproducts + " WHERE " + sColumnNameFamily + " LIKE '" + sSelectedFamily + "'";
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~De lbProd wordt gevuld met de query: " + sql + ".  Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Remove(0, 14));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        lbProd.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        lbProd.DisplayMember = sColumnNameProductcode;
        lbProd.ValueMember = sColumnNameProductcode;

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

    }

    private void lbProd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productcode = lbProd.Text;
        VeldenVullen();
    }

    private void VeldenVullen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~Geselecteertde productcode = " + productcode + ".");

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sDBproducts + " WHERE " + sColumnNameProductcode + " LIKE '" + productcode + "'";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    tbProductcode.Text = productcode;
                    tbProdOmschrijving.Text = dr[queryTaal + sColumnNameProductDescription].ToString();

                    // cm AND inches if language is ENI, else only cm
                    if (queryTaal == ENI)
                    {
                        tbAfm.Text = dr[sColumnNameSizeCM].ToString() + " " + dr[sColumnNameSizeInch].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tbAfm.Text = dr[sColumnNameSizeCM].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Er is een fout gemaakt tijdens het inlezen van alle productgegevens uit de database." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                "Contacteer de ICT afdeling." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, 
                "Ooooops! Er is iets fout gegaan...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi trigger is caused by the triggering of events. In your constructor you call `InitializeComponent();` This method binds all event listners to there controls (for example the `lbCat_SelectedIndexChanged`). This means that whenever the selected index of said control is changed the code in that method will be executed. Both you changing the index inside the code or a user doing it with the mouse/keyboard count as a valid trigger.

Your constructor triggers some of these events causing your 'loop'. To resolve this you should check if the event is triggered by either the user or your code. A cheap and easy way to do this is to put a bool in your code that is set to false until you are done loading.

so your constructor:

```
    private bool mIsLoaded;    
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine(" Opstart tijd" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
        conn.Open(); 

       //the rest of your code here...

        lbTaal.SetSelected(0, true);   // NL is pre-selected
        mIsLoaded = true;
    }
```

and then your event:

```
    private void lbCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!mIsLoaded) {
                 return;
            }
            //FAMILIE LISTBOX VULLEN ADHV GEKOZEN CATEGORIE
            queryCategorie = lbCat.Text.Remove(1);
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~GEKOZEN CATEGORIE: " + queryCategorie + ". Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Remove(0, 14));
            lbFamVullen();
        }
```

I only did this for one of your events. But you want to include the if statement in all events (unless you want them to trigger even when the system is initializing).

Some offtopic things I noticed in your code:

- In your `VeldenVullen()` method you have a try catch statement. You are closing your connection inside the try block. This means that when you have a exception, the connection is never closed.
- In your custructor you call the conn.open() I'm guessing to use it later on in one of the other methods where you close it. This way you can only execute one method before you run into the fact that your connection is closed when you access the database. Its better to open a connection at the same spot as where your using it. And closing it directly after.
- I'm dutch myself so I could figure out your comments. But when posting a question on SO its better to translate them to English so everyone can understand them.
- **You left a connection string in the question including username and password**

Comment: Thanks @Nick Otten! Is there a way to trigger once during initialization? That way it would cascade once I am guessing?

Comment: @dreojs16 : Yes, The ugly way to do it is to keep track of the cascading sate (a extra bool field that tracks if the event has already executed during initialization). A more clean way would be to move the cascading code out of the event to its own private void. Then both the event and your constructor can call the 'cascading method'.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm that way, @Nick Otten! And thanks for all the other usefull offtopic tips too!

Comment: @dreojs16 No problem! best of luck